# pass an array to server from an input tag's "value" attribute

Tags: php, html, post

I was trying to pass &_POST with a key pointing to an array within the associative array, and I tried putting the array in the "name" attribute in the "input" tag. It didn't work, it was passed to the server as a string. That gives me two questions:

1. What allows PHP to read the "name" attribute of "input" as an assoc array instead of just as a string?
2. How can I pass through the array that I would like to pass through? The code is below.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id]" name="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id]" value="['galleries', 'name']"/>
```

The code below is exactly what I want (just without the array as a string):

```
Array
(
    [tables] => Array
        (
            [stock_details] => Array
                (
                    [print_id] => 4
                    [gallery_id] => 3
                )

        )

    [options] => Array
        (
            [field_name_swap] => Array
                (
                    [gallery_id] => ['galleries', 'name'] //these lines (1)
                    [print_id] => ['prints', 'photo_id'] // (2)
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass through the array that I would like to pass through? The code is below.

For this your salvation is making array on object and encoding/decoding it as json string:

```
$json = json_encode($array_given);
echo "<input type='hidden' name='array' value='{$json}' />";
```

Now at the receiving script you just decode the given data:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
```

see the [working demo](http://tarex.ru/testdir/test6.php)

Answer (score 3):

In php each value in the array would need to be in its own field

```
<input type="hidden" id="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id][0]" name="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id][0]" value="galleries"/>
<input type="hidden" id="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id][1]" name="options[field_name_swap][gallery_id][1]" value="name"/>
```